# WARN: Unable to load JNA library (OS: Mac OS X 12.2) warning when running flutter app on release mode. (M1 Mac)

Tags: android, flutter, macos, apple-m1

I  built a simple tic-tac-toe app on Flutter. It works in debug mode without any problem, but when I run it in release mode it gives me an error:

```
WARN: Unable to load JNA library (OS: Mac OS X 12.2)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/rza/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna10193542212619812140.tmp: dlopen(/Users/rza/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna10193542212619812140.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/rza/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna10193542212619812140.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/jna10193542212619812140.tmp' (no such file)
```

I'm running the app in release mode in a virtual Android machine.

I am assuming it is about CPU architecture. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. We can't help you debug without the smallest example of runnable code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 41):

Just had this error as well. This happens with flutter 2.10.1 on a mac with M1.

I got rid of it by doing a

```
$ flutter clean
```

in my project directory.

Comment: You are amazing thank you. But I would like to know how "flutter clean" works? Because the incompatible files are not located in project folder.

Comment: I don't know for sure what is done by flutter clean - however, it claims to clean up Xcode workspace which may include artifacts stored anywhere (as Xcode has a habit to store things in places one wouldn't expect or does even know that they exist). It cleans up several artifacts that may have been created during a previous flutter run or flutter build command and which may get reused by flutter upon further runs or builds. When migrating flutter to a new version it has a chance to resolve many issues encountered then.

Comment: In my case this command broke some things (gradle custom config) and did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 9):

It's an issue with old build files. Just delete build files manually or run

`flutter clean`

Answer (score 0):

for me also it it was happening because of a switch to new flutter version (using fvm tool) and having other version with old flutter version installed in the emulator

flutter clean helped for sure after this + uninstall the app on the emulator